# Name id in GROUP BY clause is ambiguous; it may refer to multiple columns in the SELECT-list at [28:146]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In this query (by the way, I'm just learning BigQuery and SQL)

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
  SELECT
    status_2 as id, utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign, 
    utm_term, ga_client_id as client_id
  FROM `my file` 
  WHERE length(status_2) > 5
), (
  SELECT id, utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign, utm_term, client_id 
  FROM `another file` 
  WHERE id is not null
) 
GROUP BY id, utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign, utm_term, client_id
```

I'm getting this error (for each):

> Name id in GROUP BY clause is ambiguous; it may refer to multiple columns in the SELECT-list at [28:146]

How do I correct it?

Comment: Your query just looks broken.  Why would you want a Cartesian product?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Looks your query may not achieve what you want. Do you want to get all rows from both subqueries? Or do you want to join them by producing the cartesian product? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union in stead of a group by.

```
SELECT
    a.status_2 as id, a.utm_source, a.utm_medium, a.utm_campaign, 
    a.utm_term, a.ga_client_id as client_id
  FROM `my file` a
  WHERE length(a.status_2) > 5
UNION
SELECT b.id, b.utm_source, b.utm_medium, b.utm_campaign, b.utm_term, b.client_id 
  FROM `another file` b
  WHERE b.id is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ambiguous error, it just means that you're querying from more than one table with a field named id. You need to specify which id you are referring to.

As others have mentioned, it would be good to know what you're trying to accomplish.  Do you want a UNION of two tables into one single select, or do you want to JOIN two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you’re using id twice and each id refer to a different table.

You can use alias to avoid that ambiguous id.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
  SELECT
    status_2 as mf.id, mf.utm_source, mf.utm_medium, mf.utm_campaign, 
    mf.utm_term, mf.ga_client_id as mf.client_id
  FROM `my file` mf
  WHERE length(status_2) > 5
), (
  SELECT af.id, af.utm_source, af.utm_medium, af.utm_campaign, af.utm_term, af.client_id 
  FROM `another file` af
  WHERE id is not null
) 
GROUP BY mf.id, af.utm_source, af.utm_medium, af.utm_campaign, af.utm_term, mf.client_id
```